# Debian - How to run ffmpeg in screen from crontab

Tags: ffmpeg, debian, display

I got the problem with running my ffmpeg command in screen from crontab.

If I just run the screen manualy and then run my ffmpeg command manualy in this screen, it working fine.
The command I run is like that:

```
ffmpeg -v info -i rtsp://xxxx:xxxx/Streaming/Channels/102 -c:v copy -c:a copy -bufsize 100k -pix_fmt yuv420p -flags -global_header -hls_time 10 -hls_list_size 6 -hls_wrap 10 -start_number 1 /srv/www/stream/cam_one.m3u8
```

But I got the problem with run it automatically through crontab, I got this code in my crontab

```
/usr/bin/screen -dmS kamera_one ffmpeg -v info -i rtsp://xxxx:xxxx/Streaming/Channels/102 -c:v copy -c:a copy -bufsize 100k -pix_fmt yuv420p -flags -global_header -hls_time 10 -hls_list_size 6 -hls_wrap 10 -start_number 1 /srv/www/stream/cam_one.m3u8
```

It just don't popup the screen windows with my command, the list of screens is still empty.

Do you have some hints, how to do it?
Thanks